# zeroing memory area of a structure in c

Tags: c, struct, memset

I have following structure and i want to initialize it to zero.

```
struct example {
     int a;
     int b;
     char c;
};
struct example mystruct;
```

I can memset mystruct to zero in following ways:

```
memset(&mystruct, 0, sizeof(mystruct));
```

or

```
mystruct = (struct example) {0};
```

Is the second way is equal to the first one?

Note that i want to initialize mystruct variable to zero not only at variable definition, maybe for reusing it.

Comment: Do you care about padding bytes?

Comment: Yeah. Anyways size of struct will includes padding bytes.

Comment: Of course the size will include them. But do you care about the content of those bytes?

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your case, they will be equivalent (*disregarding the padding bytes*).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9/ P21, (*emphasis mine*)

> **If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members
>   of an aggregate**, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known
>   size than there are elements in the array, the **remainder of the aggregate shall be
>   initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and, regarding the initialization of static storage duration objects, P10 (*again emphasis mine*)

> [...] If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
>   explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — **if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;**
>
> — **if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
>   and any padding is initialized to zero bits;**
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
>   rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

---

For sake of completeness, as mentioned in the [below comment by  Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta):

> *all **remaining members** will be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration. And the standard does not mandate anything for the padding bits of the top level object*

which indicates, the assignment will differ from the `memset()` call in case of the first object / member, for the padding values.

Comment: I don't agree. My reading of the quoted reference to C11 if that **all remaining members** will be initialized implicitely the same as objects that have static storage duration. And the standard does not mandate anything for the padding bits of the top level object.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I dont deny it..it's correct. Updated my answer to address that.

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not equal.

The first is more low-level, it will set all bits of the value to 0, including those that are not part of any member (padding).

The latter is only guaranteed to set the actual members to zero, so it might be faster since it has the opportunity to touch less memory.

Comment: I believe, in later case also, the padding will be set to zero (as in static storage), is not it?

Comment: Are you really sure that the latter will be faster? `memset` can be a highly optimized low level routine...

Comment: @SergeBallesta No, of course I'm not sure, hence "might be faster". And of course the compiler knows this, and will just implement the clearing using a call to `memset()` if that is the best choice.

Comment: Your last comment makes it clear enough (anyway already upvoted...)